# PageSpeed and YSlow don't recognize gzip

Tags: .htaccess, gzip

I know this question has been asked several times on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find anything that worked for me in those questions.

I have a website hosted by BlueHost, and I am trying to enable gzip compression.

Here is (the relevant part of) my .htaccess file:

```
#GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript application/x-javascript text/plain text/html text/css text/x-component text/xml application/json application/xml alpplication/xhtml+xml

</ifmodule>
```

This code was given to me by BlueHost.

If I run Google's PageSpeed Insights, it recognizes the compression.  However,  when I run GTMetrix (which does PageSpeed and YSlow), neither of them recognize the gzip'd content.  Also, I checked on http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php and I am serving gzip'd content.

Did I do something wrong, or does GTMetrix have a bug?